# Ubuntu for windows - lsscsi not working

Tags: bash

I have Ubuntu for windows installed on my windows machine. I am able to use the terminal just fine. When I try to use

```
sudo lsscsi
```

I get no results. As if the virtual machine cannot detect any of my devices. Specifically I'm trying to get it to detect my Ultrium 3000. When I try using

```
sudo lspci
```

I get an error

```
cannot open /proc/bus/pci.
```

When browsing the ubuntu file system /proc/bus does exist but has no subdirectories or files.
Is what I am trying to do possible? Or will I have to properly install ubuntu as dual boot?
All I really want to do is flash my Ultrium with it's firmware. I've been able to get .E file for it and found some instructions for flashing it with this file.

```
sudo sg_write_buffer -b 4k -I Z6ED_019_233.E -m 4 /dev/sg3
sudo sg_write_buffer -m 5 /dev/sg3
```

but this fails because /dev/sg3 is not a thing. Which is why I was trying to detect where my ultrium was in the ubuntu filing system.
I have to use this .E file because the .frm file I need to install via hpe software is locked behind a "paywall". I quote it because they won't even let me pay to get the file, I have to have a serial number for a device still under warranty. HPE is evil.
Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu over WSL is not running on bare metal so it's not actually connected directly to your devices. Many of these kinds of hardware tasks cannot be done using WSL. You will need to install Ubuntu in dual boot config if you want to use Ubuntu directly on top of your hardware

Answer (score -1):

Try installing gnome "sudo apt install gnome -y" and then runing "sudo lshw -C display". Hope it will work

Comment: Why install gnome ?

Comment: not sure.. I was trying every possible thing that I could do and out of no where, the trick worked in my testing system xD